# Macroeconomics, price setting and wage setting

Tags: consumption

What happens to prcie setting and wage setting when consumption falls? I already looked at what happens to IS-curve and LM-curve.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Economics SE! we have a policy regarding homework questions where users must demonstrate effort using text, markdown syntax and/or images space provided in the text of his question submission for the site. Using only images as proof of work is insufficient. for more details see:https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions